# Set build order in catkin: generate custom messages before generating ros_lib

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, ros-lib, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Quesiton:** When using catkin to build a project, how do you set one package to finish compiling before another executes?

---

**Background:** I am making a robot with custom messages/services on an Arduino using catkin. The project layout is rather similar to the [Clearpath Robotics Husky](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel) where the project is separated into packages: msgs, hardware, description, ... etc. Everything works and the Arduino even compiles and uploads though catkin_make commands as outlined by this rosserial_arduino [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/CMake). The current project layout is as follows:

- **catkin_ws/**
- **src/**

  - **robot_msgs:** description of custom ros messages/services (Status.msg & Command.srv)
  - **robot_hardware:** source code for Arduino (runs rosserial_client & rosserial_arduino)
  - **robot_description:** robot description files (urdf/xacro)
  - **robot_viz:** opens RVIZ with robot model

---

**Problem**: When building from a fresh install (no build/devel folders in the main catkin workspace), the issue arises when executing `catkin_make` for the first time. It seems that the `robot_hardware` package builds and compiles a new `ros_lib` before `robot_msgs` can add `Status.msg` or `Command.srv` to the project directory (robot_msgs folder is absent in the final ros_lib folder). However, if `robot_hardware` is temporarily removed while `catkin_make` is run, then afterwards replaced and `catkin_make` is run again, everything compiles and robot_msgs now exists in ros_lib. Is there anyway to add a dependency to the CMakeLists.txt file in `robot_hardware` to force it to go last so that the project compiles using `catkin_make` without tinkering with the project folders in a such a way?

---

**Supplementary:**

robot_hardware/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(robot_hardware)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rosserial_arduino
  rosserial_client
  robot_msgs
)

catkin_package()

rosserial_generate_ros_lib(
  PACKAGE rosserial_arduino
  SCRIPT make_libraries.py
)

# Added as a suggestion from @jayess (Sept 15 '17)
add_dependencies(robot_hardware_ros_lib 
    robot_msgs_generate_messages
    robot_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    robot_msgs_generate_messages_eus
    robot_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
    robot_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
    robot_msgs_generate_messages_py
)

rosserial_configure_client(
  DIRECTORY firmware
  TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_ARDUINO_TOOLCHAIN}
)

rosserial_add_client_target(firmware robot_base ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(firmware robot_base-upload)
```

robot_msgs/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(robot_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  std_msgs
)

add_message_files(FILES
  Status.msg
)

add_service_files(FILES
  Command.srv
)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs message_runtime)
```

runtime error on fresh build

```
...
[86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/robot_base.dir/robot_hardware.cpp.obj
/home/user/catkin_ws/src/robot_hardware/firmware/robot_hardware.cpp:52:34: fatal error: robot_msgs/Command.h: No such file or directory
#include <robot_msgs/Command.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270980/set-build-order-in-catkin:-generate-custom-messages-before-generating-ros_lib/) by [djiglesias](https://answers.ros.org/users/29395/djiglesias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this solution https://answers.ros.org/question/200995/rosserial_arduino-generate-dependent-packages-before-make_libraries/?answer=209434#post-id-209434.

I found it by [Googling "rosserial_generate_ros_lib site:answers.ros.org"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rosserial_generate_ros_lib+site%3Aanswers.ros.org)

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djiglesias](https://answers.ros.org/users/29395/djiglesias/) on 2017-09-15**:
Great find, slightly embarrassed that I didn't find that sooner. Unfortunately, the solution did not work. I found the targets and added them as dependencies to the `robot_hardware/CMakeLists.txt`. I deleted the build and devel folders to start fresh but the behaviour is still the same.

Any ideas?

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2017-09-16**:
Try `robot_msgs_gencpp` instead of `robot_msgs_generate_messages_cpp` and others. Also, `catkin_make_isolated` will build one package at a time in dependency order.

**Comment by [djiglesias](https://answers.ros.org/users/29395/djiglesias/) on 2017-09-18**:
@kmhallen

`catkin_make_isolated` compiles fine with the `robot_msgs` building to ros_lib as desired, but removes the ability to upload code to the Arduino via command line. Also, substituting `robot_msgs_gencpp`  in place of the other dependencies had no effect on the build behaviour yet again.